# Display Table Rows Using Async in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular6, ngfor, angular-ngfor

I need to display the result of the JSON response in a table. I already figure it out using this below

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of results$ | async">
    <td>{{result.max_temp}}</td>
</tr>
```

But i wanna do something like this below and its not working. 
Can anyone help me out on how to fix this?

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of (results$ | async)?.max_temp">
    <td>{{result}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `max_temp` is iterable?

Comment: Please update max_temp value

Comment: @Buczkowski. The first code above is working. i wanna do something like the second code

Comment: @Joseph yes, I know and you want iterate over `max_temp` that's why I'm asking if it's iterable eg. Array?

Comment: @Buczkowski. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these two solution which I can suggest. You can use any of them.

Solution 1:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="results$ | async as resolvedResult">
  <tr *ngFor="let result of resolvedResult.max_temp">
    <td>{{result}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Solution 2:

```
<ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="asyncTemplate;context:{resolvedResult: results$ | async}">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #asyncTemplate let-resolvedResult="resolvedResult">
  <tr *ngFor="let result of resolvedResult.max_temp">
    <td>{{result}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Please note, from the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue):

> The Angular ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Comment: I needed it to be one tr only. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph Didn't get that? one tr only? Them why loop? Are you saying you don't want `ng-container`?

Answer (score 0):

In second example you try to access `max_temp` property of results$ (which is probably observable that's return Array) and it doesn't have that property. 
First example works because you simply access that property on actual item (through iteration) of that Array.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: @Joseph Depends how you want show values from `max_temp`. Values separated by comma in single `td?`